# Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, uwp

For my Unity-UWP project, I want to interact with iBeacons.

I wanted to add the library to my project, but I can't seem to locate it.
What do I have to do, in order to use it with my Unity project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile a dll separately that interacts with `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll` then include the dll in the in your project under the `Assets/Plugins/WSA` folder to add it as a plugin. Once you do that you can reference the DLL like you would in any normal .NET project as if you added a reference to the dll.

There are some other requirements beyond that (For example you also need to make a 2nd version of the plugin compiled with the full .NET framework with the same type names and version number to be used in-editor), see the unity documentation "[Windows Store Apps: Plugins on .NET Scripting Backend](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-plugins.html)" for the full details.